# In Java, is there a shortcut way to implement interfaces?

Tags: java, interface

Can we use stub methods for implementing interfaces ? i.e., suppose I get a message that says I must implement `ServletRequestAttributeListener and HttpSessionListener`  - what do I need to do? Can I simply put the method signature, and use dummy values?

Comment: Why would you implement an interface and not adhere to its contract properly?

Comment: @monadic - Well, in my case just to have a running system and then later I can go back and fix it. i.e, I'm putting it on the backburner, and will later come back.

Comment: Yes you can create stub methods, but it almost sounds as if that class should be abstract then.

Comment: @monadic: particularly in the Servlet API there are this kind of interfaces like `Filter`, `ServletRequestListener`, `HttpSessionListener`, etc. You are however not necessarily required to do any business job in all methods. For example, you may not be interested in doing `init()` or in hooking on *both* `created` and `destroyed` events, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand that you're in general talking about those `XxxListener` interfaces in the Servlet API.

- http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/package-summary.html
- http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/package-summary.html

If you're not interested in hooking on the event, just do nothing. Leave the method body empty. If necesary, add a comment like `NOOP` (no operation) to suppress the IDE "empty body" warning.

```
@Override
public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event) {
    // NOOP.
}
```

For other interfaces, it depends on their contract. I'd read their javadocs to be sure.

Comment: @Adel yes, and using that annotation is [recommended](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/94361/when-do-you-use-javas-override-annotation-and-why)!

Comment: And it shuts up the IDE from generating warnings for unused parameters :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can as long as you understand the main drawback of this: the contract provided by the interface will not be satisfied by your class.  This may be a problem if others end up using your code.

Answer (score 0):

Declare your class abstract doesn't force you to implement interface's method, but you will need to do it in a subclass:

```
public interface bar{ public void aMethod();}
public abstract class foo implements bar{ 
     //aMethod could be not implemented here, but in the first concrete subclass of foo
}
```

Comment: Hmm, Oh, that's interesting. I have alot of food for thought now.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider investing some time into looking at design patterns. I think what you are looking for is [The Template Method Pattern](http://java.dzone.com/articles/design-patterns-template-method). A good book for exploring design patterns is [Head First Design Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596007124). It's an easy read and has some great info.